# How to change query parameter value of tRestClient

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

I am new in talend. I am working on this from last 2 days but not able to do it. I want to consume api data into my database. I have this api => 
 `http://api.dss.adapt-odisha.com/aagro?url=https://mausam.imd.gov.in/api/nowcast_district_api.php`

which giving me data of all districts. I am able to consume all district data, but my requirement is, i want to load data of for few districts and my url supports only one district id as query parameter like this=>

```
 http://api.dss.adapt-odisha.com/aagro?url=https://mausam.imd.gov.in/api/nowcast_district_api.php?id=204
```

and like this

```
http://api.dss.adapt-odisha.com/aagro?url=https://mausam.imd.gov.in/api/nowcast_district_api.php?id=215
```

these url showing data of only that district which i passed in query parameter. I am able to consume all district data, but i want to store data of these districts only. How can i achieve it?

i have tried this till now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there ! What you need to do is to build a list of district that you want to get (here I put a tFixedFlow with fixed value, but you could have a file, a DB query, etc).

[image]

Pass this to a tFlowToIterate, this will allow you to iterate over the district list : there will be an API call for each district in your list.
Configure the 2d tFixedFlow to retrieve the current district from tFlowToIterate :
[image]
Adapt the tRestClientUrl like this :

```
"http://api.dss.adapt-odisha.com/aagro?url=https://mausam.imd.gov.in/api/nowcast_district_api.php?id="+row2.district
```

Comment: in first tFixedFlowInput how can i place list of districts?